# max-height transition in webkit browser

Tags: css, angularjs

I am trying to animate ng-if using max-height property, but cannot make it work in Chrome. (It works in Firefox.) 
Am I missing something or it is a bug in Chrome?

```
.slide-down-up {
  background:green;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-down-up.ng-enter {
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;    
    max-height: 0;
}   

.slide-down-up.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
.slide-down-up.ng-leave {
    max-height: 600px;  
}

.slide-down-up.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    max-height: 0;  
}

.slide-down-up.ng-leave {
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out; // doesn't work
    transition: max-height 1s ease-out; // works    
}
```

Here is the plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/VpRQK4sNyXnu6U8SbxtP?p=preview

Comment: It works for me in chrome.

Comment: @TarunDugar, `max-height` is animatable: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height ... plus, it's working for OP in FF, and for me in both FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/MyHLM0lHAPwJGCZ656Iw/)

Fix delay solution:

Put cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1) transition function for element.

```
.text {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
  &.full {
    max-height: 1000px;
    transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}
```